# Update Bootstrap split button text and function with dropdown button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a split-button dropdown; Initally, the text of the button is 'Websites' and it does not do anything upon clicking. I want make it so whichever option is clicked from the dropdown, the text of that option and onClick functionality is updated in the button.

For example, I have a split button with 'Websites' text, and the dropdown has 'Google', 'Yahoo', 'Bing' as options. Each option leads to their respective website. If 'Google' is clicked, I want to replace 'Webites' with 'Google' (or a custom text) and now when the split button is clicked, it would go to Google's website as well.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Websites</button>
  <button onClick="updateDropdown()" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.bing.com/">Bing</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bjf21pxj/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  var anchor = $(e.currentTarget);
  var href = anchor.attr('href');
  var text = anchor.text();
    var button = anchor.closest('.btn-group').find('button:first-child');
  button.attr('data-url', href);
  button.text(text);
  button.on('click', gotoUrl);
});

function gotoUrl(e){
e.preventDefault();
//use window.open because we can't open these urls in jsfiddle.
window.open($(e.currentTarget).attr('data-url'));

//Maybe this is what you want in your site.
//window.location.href = $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-url')

}
```

Here is a working js fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/dattaproffs/bjf21pxj/1/

I don't know what updateDropdown does so i just left it in there.